# How to extract HTML from updated DOM using Capybara Webkit driver?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have a page that injects some text into the DOM: `'Success!'`.

The Javascript code works because I see the expected text in the screenshot, and the spec passes:

```
page.visit '/'

save_and_open_screenshot

expect( page).to have_content 'Success!'

puts page.html
```

However, the `page.html` is not updated. It does not have the injected text.

How do I get the HTML for the updated DOM?

EDIT: I found that the issue is caused by an iframe. The iframe is not added to the page.html, but it is added to the page.

EDIT #2: It turns out that the 'Success!' content is not in the iframe. So maybe the context is switching to the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Found one workaround which is OK:

```
html = page.evaluate_script( 'document.documentElement.innerHTML' )
```

I guess one could use JS or jQuery finder to find the expected `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

For the entire page body you can do this:

```
page.body
```

For any element in particular

```
page.find(".my-div").base.inner_html
```

Check out the full API here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/blob/master/lib/capybara/webkit/node.rb

Comment: I think I tried this. I don't think it works when JS updates the DOM after the page loads.

Comment: It works with the things I'm doing with lots of dynamic js dom updates. There may be something else going on. I've dug through the Webkit source and I can see it invokes a getInnerHTML call to the Webkit server, which delegates to capybara.js call of this.getNodes[index].innerHTML. So as long as the node is there in the dom, it should work.

Comment: Also, another tip: For some reason in our app, we had automatic_reload = false. When we recently upgraded to the latest(1.4.x->1.7.x) we had all sorts of weird issues that were ultimately solved by removing this setting, which defaults to true I believe.  This setting affects whether you can have unattached nodes in the dom.